# How to set up a password for openrdf workbench?

Tags: configuration, passwords, rdf, semantics, sesame

I have successfully installed [Openrdf Repository](http://www.openrdf.org/) (sesame 2.3.2) and Openrdf workbench however I do not know how to set up a user and a password to protect Openrdf workbench. I suppose that there is --somewhere -- a configuration file.

Can somebody give me a hint how to create a user and set up a password for openrdf workbench?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to password protect at the servlet container level. Are you using Tomcat? Here's what I used to set up basic authentication with Tomcat 6:

**web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Sesame Workbench</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>sesame-user</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>          

<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Sesame Workbench</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
  <description>The role required for Sesame workbench</description>
  <role-name>sesame-user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**tomcat-users.xml**

```
<role rolename="sesame-user"/>
<user username="workbench" password="workbench" roles="sesame-user"/>
```

Comment: I do not know why but it does not work. I mean I can open workbench without giving username and password.

Comment: My fault, I assumed something would work without testing it. It seems you can't use the main web.xml to protect individual webapp URLs (but you can use /* to protect everything served by Tomcat). So if you want to protect only the workbench, you would add the above snippet to web.xml for that webapp (e.g. webapps/openrdf-workbench/WEB-INF/web.xml).